# I need help transferring UPS dsn from XP to Windows 7 64bit

Tags: windows-7-x64, dsn, ups

I'm "upgrading" our Windows computer used for shipping. As part of our workflow, ShipGear exports to UPS On Line World Ship (UOWLS) via a mapped "keyed import" inside UOLWS. I used the UPS Utility in menu Start->UPS to do a database back up. ShipGear also has its own MSSQL 2008 database which it backed up as well.

I pulled the hard drive with windows XP out and put in the new SSD drive, installed Windows 7 64 bit, installed UOLWS and ShipGear, restored both from their back ups. Everything seemed ok except for the transfer... I tried copying over folders from the previous C:\UPS on the old hard drive (anticipating this) but that didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UPS technician for the area came out and got it fixed. All of the keyed import data was still in the new UPS from the database restore, the problem was the DSN wasn't available so that saved mapping does not show up in UOLWS's import dialog.

And the DSN can't be found in Start->Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Data Sources (because this is for the 64 bit ODBC)

Instead, the 32 bit one needs to be used... to access 32 bit data sources, navigate to C:\Windows\SysWOW64 and make a shortcut for odbcad32.exe to your desktop or UPS folder. Run C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe to get exposure to the 32 bit odbc data source from ShipGear (by adding the SQL10 driver, selecting the source, typing login information). ALSO, the connection name must be identical to the name used on your previous Windows XP installation.

I hope this helps someone!! :)